# Flutter: Display all users from flutterstore excluding the currently logged in user

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a chat ui for my flutter app. Right now I have managed to display all the users from firestore. But I want to show them excluding the current user logged in to the app.

Here is my code:

```
class Chats extends StatefulWidget {
  final String chatUserId;
  Chats({this.chatUserId});
  @override
  _ChatState createState() => _ChatState(
    chatUserId:this.chatUserId,
  );
}

class _ChatState extends State<Chats> {
  TextEditingController chatController = TextEditingController();

  Future<QuerySnapshot> chatUsers;
  final String chatUserId;
  _ChatState({this.chatUserId});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setState(() {
      chatUsers = usersRef.getDocuments();
    });
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: header(context,titleText: 'GupShup'),
      body:FutureBuilder(
      future: chatUsers,
      builder: (context,snapshot){
        if(snapshot.hasData){
        List<ChatResult> results = [];
        snapshot.data.documents.forEach((doc){
        User user = User.fromDocument(doc);
        ChatResult result = ChatResult(user);
        results.add(result);
        });
        return ListView(
            children: results,
        );
      }
      return circularProgress();
      }
      ),
    );
  }
}

     

class ChatResult extends StatelessWidget {
  final User user;
  ChatResult(this.user);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color:Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
           GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> ChatScreen(
            username: user.displayName,
            uuid: Uuid().v4().toString()))),
            child:
            ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(user.photoUrl),
              ),
              title: Text(user.displayName,style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
              subtitle: Text('message'),
              ),
           ),
          Divider(
            height: 2.0,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Here's the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Roqeo.png)

Now, currently Nilima Bordoloi has been logged in. How to hide this user?

Also, is there any way to look this page more beautiful like whatsapp or messenger?

Any help would be appreciable.

Thank You...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Chats extends StatefulWidget {
  final String chatUserId;
  Chats({this.chatUserId});
  @override
  _ChatState createState() => _ChatState(
    chatUserId:this.chatUserId,
  );
}

class _ChatState extends State<Chats> {
  TextEditingController chatController = TextEditingController();

  Future<QuerySnapshot> chatUsers;
  final String chatUserId;
  _ChatState({this.chatUserId});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setState(() {
      chatUsers = usersRef.getDocuments();
    });
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: header(context,titleText: 'GupShup'),
      body:FutureBuilder(
      future: chatUsers,
      builder: (context,snapshot){
        if(snapshot.hasData){
        List<ChatResult> results = [];
        snapshot.data.documents.forEach((doc){
        User user = User.fromDocument(doc);
        
        //check here if the uid of user is != chatUserId
        //if it is not,(meaning it is not the currently logged in user) add 
        //him to results
        if(user.uid != chatUserId.uid){
        ChatResult result = ChatResult(user);
        results.add(result);
        }
        });
        return ListView(
            children: results,
        );
      }
      return circularProgress();
      }
      ),
    );
  }
}

     

class ChatResult extends StatelessWidget {
  final User user;
  ChatResult(this.user);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color:Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
           GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> ChatScreen(
            username: user.displayName,
            uuid: Uuid().v4().toString()))),
            child:
            ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(user.photoUrl),
              ),
              title: Text(user.displayName,style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
              subtitle: Text('message'),
              ),
           ),
          Divider(
            height: 2.0,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```